# Any special reason why object/instance of a class is created inside main method?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and my questions might seem too silly. But please help me with this as I haven't found an answer as to why is it that we always create objects inside a main method.

I am trying to execute the below code as given in a book I am reading. But there is no main method in this program. So I am trying to see how can i get this executed. I even tried creating another class in the same package. But I am clueless.

```
public class MyDate {

   private int day=1;
   private int month=1;
   private int year=2000;
   public MyDate(int day,int month,int year)
   {
      this.day=day;
      this.month=month;
      this.year=year;
   }
   public MyDate(MyDate date)
   {
      this.day=date.day;
      this.month=date.month;
      this.year=date.year;
   }
   public MyDate addDays(int moreDays)
   {
      MyDate newDate=new MyDate(this);
      newDate.day=newDate.day+moreDays;
      return newDate;
   }        
   @Override
   public String toString()
   {        
      return " "+day+ "-"+month+ "-"+year;
   }
}
```

So I tried to create another class with main method in this very same package. I created object of `MyDate` class there and tried to access the method `addDays`. But even thats not working. The program is written below.

```
public class NewClass {
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      MyDate date1 = null,c;
      c=date1.addDays(5);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you provide example code?

Comment: That's not true. I can create an object in any method: `private King getKing() { return new Maroun(); }`.

Comment: You always dont have to create your objects in main method... u can call any other method from main() and create objects there...

Comment: @MarounMaroun lol, remember that public class King extends Melquiades {} ;) still, 1+ from me :)

Comment: Please vote to repoen, the question is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Class has a boundry of access because it is just a container which holds properties and methods within it. While Instance / Object represent ownership of Class. So, to access Class data you need to instantiate a reference to that class (called Object), through which you can access data.

Answer (score 0):

That's is because a programm needs a single static entry point (the main method itself) and most of the functionality is usually implemented in classes, to use the functions provided by a class you need an instance (object of a class).

For the edited version of your question, you forgot to call the constructor:

```
public class NewClass {
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      MyDate date1 = new MyDate(1,1,2000); // new calls the constructor (creates a new object)
      MyDate c=date1.addDays(5);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the case. If we want to invoke any method in any class we have to initialize that class (As you said it as creating Object). In `Java` main method is the starting point of a program that's why many occasion you see such things..